# Datagridview checkbox selects all - then save each cell to its own variable?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

After working with some fine people on here I converted a listview I was using to display my sql table using datagrid view instead.  Now trying to work with the data on the grid I'm running into some issues, bear in mind I have no experience with datagrid and I'm feeling my way through it.

The last column on the grid is a checkbox column.  I'm trying to figure out how when the box is checked it selects everything in that row?

The next thing I was trying to learn is how to save each of the cell's contents of that selected to a variable, say "cell1" "cell2" ect.

While trying to learn how to get some data I figured this out however you have to manually selected each cell and if you click the checkbox it breaks it.

```
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    Dim FirstValue As Boolean = True
    Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
    For Each cell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
        If Not FirstValue Then
            TextBox2.Text += ", "
        End If
        TextBox2.Text += cell.Value.ToString()
        FirstValue = False
    Next
```

Just some info to build a better mental picture here.  The datagrid is filled with a table of all the products in the stock room based on the users search for what they need, say gloves at their workstation.  I want them to check the box of the row that represents the gloves they need.  That row contains sells for that glove such as amount, location, description..etc.  I want to be able to save each cell to a variable so that they can "add" to the cart, later then submit which I'll be inserting into an orders sql table for the stockroom to pull up later and fulfill.

Comment: a) If the DGV is bound (it should be) then work with the data in the datasource not the rows, cells or control b) When they check a row, what you should care about is the item it represents (the row).  c) The cart DataSource then cares mostly just what Product is selected for creating an Order row.  Not sure why you need each cell - those represent Product data (it sounds like)

Comment: Well the order tables requires so much information to be inserted.  So the data some, not all of the individual cell's of that row I want to appear in certain textbox's of the cart page once there.  So I can then submit and each textbox will equal each sql insert.  May be better ways but this is just what I know.

You and I worked on getting this grid up and running last week.  So when you say if it is "bound", I'm not sure.  If you recall we did `myDataTable.Load(rsMPCS)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable`

Comment: `DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable` means it is bound to a datasource (myDataTable).  So what matters is that row, that data not the DGV cells.  Those are just how we display information to the user.  The orders part should follow the same pattern.  There ought not be "a lot of data to copy": databases are about replationships.  Typically, an order would use the PK from Products to indicate what is being ordered, the how much, when by whom etc.  When you make an ATM withdrawal, the bank system does not copy all the user/account info to anything.  It uses your PK ID to indicate whom

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about that.  Not that I won't, just scratching my head at the moment.  Clearly I haven't be programming very long unfortunately but this is the process I suppose.  I tried implementing what Karen suggested below, not sure how to apply it exactly to mine but just in trying to copy over some of the code the only issue I have is adding the 2 columns for checkbox and status I get a value of Type cannot be converted to string.  But I'm not entirely sure if everything provided is what I should be doing to begin with.

Comment: Are you saying that if a particular row has a product_ID of say 35 then I just take the data from that particular cell "35" and using the relationship's to that copy over the information I need to the cart?  I'm going to show my ignorance here, but will selecting "where Product_ID = 35 automatically carry over what I need from the database to my cart? That's where I can confused and think that I need to grab each cell from the row selected.

Comment: One of the main roles of the Id is to represent that record elsewhere.  So when it is time to order some more #35, the orderitem table would have ProductId as 35.  There may be other stuff (size, color, quantity) but those describe the order item.  Also set of orders is usually 2 tables: if you need 30 things from 3 suppliers, you dont send out 30 orders - you send 3 orders each with multiple line items attached.  If you have Access, the NorthWinds database is not hard to come by.  You should look at how it is put together to learn a little about RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

The following the following loads mocked data into a DataTable which becomes the DataSource of the DataGridView. Button1 shows how to get each row where the DataGridview CheckBox is checked, I forego any assertion here for validating the column name exist. Lastly there are a few things that are not needed for this but is good to know.

Helpers

```
Module BindingSourceExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function CurrentRow(ByVal sender As BindingSource, ByVal Column As String) As String
        Return DirectCast(sender.Current, DataRowView).Row(Column).ToString
    End Function

End Module
```

DataGridView extension

```
Module DataGridviewExtensions
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function ExportSelectedRows(ByVal sender As DataGridView, ByVal ColumnName As String) As String()
        Return _
            (
                From row In sender.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                Where Not row.IsNewRow AndAlso CType(row.Cells(ColumnName).Value, Boolean) = True
                Let RowItem = String.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(
                row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray,
                Function(c As DataGridViewCell) If(c.Value Is Nothing, "", c.Value.ToString)))
                Select RowItem).ToArray
    End Function
End Module
```

Form code, note I used Console.WriteLine which shows in the IDE output window

```
Public Class Form1
    Private checkBoxColumnName As String = "AvailableColumn"
    Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = GetMockedData()
    End Sub
    Private Function GetMockedData() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("Identifier", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("Room", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("RoomType", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Rate", GetType(Decimal))
        dt.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumnName, GetType(Boolean))
        dt.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))

        dt.Rows.Add(10, "201A", "Suite", 98.99, False, "Incomplete")
        dt.Rows.Add(20, "101A", "Suite", 120.99, False, "Incomplete")
        dt.Rows.Add(30, "201B", "Suite", 99.99, False, "Incomplete")

        dt.AcceptChanges()

        Return dt

    End Function
    Private Sub DataGridView1SelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
        If TypeOf DataGridView1.CurrentCell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
            If DataGridView1.Columns(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name = checkBoxColumnName Then
                DataGridView1.EndEdit()
                Dim Checked As Boolean = CType(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value, Boolean)
                If Checked Then
                    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("StatusColumn").Value = "Complete"
                Else
                    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("StatusColumn").Value = "Incomplete"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdClose.Click
        Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rowArray As String() = DataGridView1.ExportSelectedRows(checkBoxColumnName)
        If rowArray.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row As String In rowArray
                Console.WriteLine(row)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

With all this laid out, I would highly recommend looking at working against the data source e.g. use a DataTable then use either a for/next to iterate rows or lambda or linq to get checked rows (DataRows). But if this is not an option then consider using the above method.